# How to remove surrounding spaces in a comma delimited string in jQuery QueryBuilder plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, whitespace, trim, query-builder

I am using jQuery [QueryBuilder](https://querybuilder.js.org/index.html) plugin. I have `in` operator with an input text. Users can type one value or a comma delimited string.

I used `value_separator: ','` but it's taking the whole value with the surrounding spaces as you see below. The expected result should be `name IN ('Alex','Anne','Marie')`

[image]

I tried to use the `valueSetter` function as below :

```
    valueSetter: function(rule, value) { 
    rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input').value = 
    rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input').val().split(",").map((item)=>item.trim()) ; }
```

So I check the current input value and then split it by comma and trim each item then return the new value but it's not working.

Any suggestion please what I am doing wrong ? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
    filters: [ 
     { id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    type: 'string',
    value_separator: ',',
    operators: ['in'],
    //this value setter to get current input value, split it by comma if it has and return with item trimmed
    valueSetter: function(rule, value) { 
    rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input').val() = 
    rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input').val().split(",").map((item)=>item.trim()) ; }
    }
    ]
 });   
 
$('#sql').on('click', function() { 
var filter = $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('getSQL', false);
console.log(filter.sql);
 });
 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://querybuilder.js.org/node_modules/sql-parser-mistic/browser/sql-parser.min.js"></script>

<div id="queryBuilder"></div>
<button type="submit" id="sql" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-rounded center-block">SQL</button>
```

Comment: To set a DOM node's value= in jquery you use `.val(new_value)` not `.value=`  (or `$("sel")[0].value=` (note the [0])`

Comment: @freedomn-m  thanks but not working with .val() i tried that before

Comment: Then your selector is probably incorrect.  Can you update your snippet to include where you've added your `trim` code?

Comment: You probably want `....val().split(",").map((item)=>item.trim()).join(",")` as it's expecting a string, not an array.

Comment: @freedomn-m  edited. check please the valuesetter function. Can you identify where is the issue ? much appreciated

Comment: It's `.val(new_value)` not `.val() = new_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `valueGetter` instead of `valueSetter`:

```js
        valueGetter: function(rule) {
          return rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input').val().split(",").map((item)=>item.trim());
        },
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
    filters: [ 
     { id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    type: 'string',
    valueGetter: function(rule) {
      return rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input').val().split(",").map((item)=>item.trim());
    },
    value_separator: ',',
    operators: ['in'] }
    ]
 });   
 
$('#sql').on('click', function() { 
var filter = $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('getSQL', false);
console.log(filter.sql);
 });
 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://querybuilder.js.org/node_modules/sql-parser-mistic/browser/sql-parser.min.js"></script>

<div id="queryBuilder"></div>
<button type="submit" id="sql" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-rounded center-block">SQL</button>
```